# Using AngularJS, How Can I Choose Not to Render a HTML Element if a Variable is Not Defined?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to resolve an issue whereby a  HTML element uses a Javascript variable to define the image it should display, but errors on load. Have a look at this line:

```
<img src="../../Images/{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png" />
```

This currently works great, except under the browser's console, it is displaying an error to say that it cannot find the literal string "{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png". I assume this is because AngularJS is loaded after the HTML elements are rendered by the browser.

How can I work around this?

I did try using the following Angular statement on the  element like so:

```
ng-if="typeof(variableData.data)!=='undefined'"
```

But I imagine this makes no difference and the browser will still display a not found error message for the .png image.

The page all functions correctly, I just don't want those error messages in the browser's console.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: just use ng-if="typeof(variableData.data)!==undefined"  . undefined is keyword in javascript its not a string

Comment: Sorry. just use ng-if="variableData.data!==undefined" . you don't even need typeof

Comment: @saiyan He doesn't even need to compare it, just write `ng-if="variableData.data"`

Comment: you could use ng-src instead of src, it creates the 'src' attribute with interpolated content and avoids the browser loads an invalid url.

Comment: @ Abhishek Pandey but it works for null also, not just undefined. He asked that if variable is not defined.

Comment: Hey @PierreEmmanuelLallemant that's actually a great suggestion. I still get the 404 error for the image though. Can I somehow tie the ng-src in with an ng-if?

Comment: If your variableData is fetched in async ($http call for example), wrap the img inside a div with a ng-if. If your variable is defined raw in the code, it should work without the ng-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`src="<img src="../../Images/{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png" />"`

to

`ng-src="<img src="../../Images/{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png" />"`
This makes sure it doesn't attempt to load until runtime of the javascript.

Changing the `ng-if` to just the variable (`ng-if="variableData.data.canEdit"`) will make sure the element is loaded after the variable.

Comment: Hey Luke. This is what I used to resolve the issue, so I'll tick your answer. My solution was the following:

<div ng-if="variableData.data.canEdit"><img ng-src="../../Images/{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png" /></div>

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-if="variableData.data"
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You have to put just variable like this

```
ng-if="variableData.data.canEdit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PierreEmmanuelLallemant for answering this one in the comments.

The solution was to use ng-src within the img element, and then wrap the img element within a div and use an ng-if. Like so:

```
<div ng-if="variableData.data.canEdit"><img ng-src="../../Images/{{variableData.data.canEdit}}.png" /></div>
```

Using ng-src ensures that when Angular loads it sets the source attribute. Wrapping the img inside a div with ng-if makes sure that anything inside the div is not rendered until variableData.data.canEdit is defined.

Many thanks